# PHP download script increases number of downloads by twice

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

I am doing a project where user can download the files by clicking download button. Upon clicking the download link, the request is redirected to the `download.php` file where actual download code resides. After downloading, the number of downloads is increases by 1 in the database. The PHP code (written in `codeigniter`) is as follows

```
public function index($filename)
    {
        $item = array_shift($this->music_m->get_by(array('upload_path'=>$filename)));
        if(count($item)){
            if (file_exists("uploads/".$filename)) {
                $item->noOfDownloads = $item->noOfDownloads + 1;
                $this->music_m->save($item, $item->id);
                $data = file_get_contents("uploads/".$filename); // Read the file's contents
                $name = $filename;
                force_download($name, $data);
            }else{
                echo "404 File Not Found";
                exit;
            }
        }else{
            echo "404 File Not Found!";
        }
    }
```

But my problem is, the number of download increases by 2 or 3 or even 6 (with IDM) instead of 1. In Linux with Firefox browser, it works fine. But in windows, in Google chrome, it increases by 2. The condition gets worst when IDM downloads the file, it increases the number of downloads by 6. I don't know where may be the error. Whether the script itself is called multiple times or what else?

Comment: That's because of multiple requests, IDM uses more than 1 connection to download the file.

Comment: Keep a session variable flag to see if download count is increased for tht session. When increasing the counter switch flag value.